# weak self always nil in asynchronous closure Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire

When I use below version of code I am able to see the self object(it is non nill aways) and do the other processing stuff.

**Without converting self to weak self**

```
    Alamofire.request(some url).responseJSON {  response in

        self.resolvedURLString = "ff"
        print("==\(self.resolvedURLString)")
    }
```

But to avoid retain cycles or for safety way (using weak self always in closures) I am using below version of code.

**By converting self to weak self**

```
    Alamofire.request(some url).responseJSON { [weak self] response in

        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

        strongSelf.resolvedURLString = "ff"
        print("==\(strongSelf.resolvedURLString)")
    }
```

but here always self become nil , I never able to print the value of resolvedURLString. How to make self as strong self or how to retain the self until closure execution ends?

**EDIT:** From AppDelegate i initiazed NetworkManager , from this class i call NetworkDownloader, in this class the actual call will happen

## AppDelegate.M

```
if let networkManager = self.networkManager {
    networkManager.downloadDataToCache()
}
```

## NetworkManager

```
let __areaDownloader = AreaDownloader(backgroundContext: backgroundContext, withDelegate: nil)
__areaDownloader.download(withSuccess: {_ in
    //Write code for core data
    self.isAreaCachingIsComplete = true
    self.checkNotificationsForCacheComplete()

}, failure: {})
```

## class AreaDownloader: NetworkDownloader

```
    override func download(withSuccess successBlock: SuccessWithJsonType?, failure failureBlock: FailureType?) {

            Alamofire.request(some url).responseJSON { [weak self] response in

                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

                strongSelf.resolvedURLString = "ff"
                print("==\(strongSelf.resolvedURLString)")
            }
}
```

Comment: We need to know more about the surroundings/environment of the code. When in your app does this run? what else happens in/around this event happening? Sounds like you fire this request and then probably dismiss the vc or something but difficult to know with whats shown above

Comment: And if you want to retain self until closure execution ends, don't use the capture list `[weak self]` as you did in your first example. A weak self is not always recommended but it really depends on the context of your code.

Comment: @Sciptable you are right the same code is giving me non nil self when i run in a initial controller . Please check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever object is that `self` refers to has gone by the time the Alamofire's completion request handler gets executed. You need to keep a strong reference to `self` somewhere until after the response handler has run. In your first example with the strong `self` the closure itself provides the strong reference. In the second example with `weak self` nothing does.

What option you choose is dependent on circumstances. Looking at your code, such as it is, you don't keep a reference to the Alamofire request anywhere so you'll probably be OK with the your first option - the object referred to by `self` doesn't keep a strong reference to the request either directly or indirectly, so there's no ownership cycle.